# Options menu not initialized in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a frame where I put different fragments in. Some has actionbar displayed, some does not. But the one given below does not display action bar as any other.

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_a, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_a) {
        //getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

This fragment is called from previous fragment like

```
AFragment aFragment = new AFragment ();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, aFragment , "fragment_a")
                            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

By the way, I do not show action bar in the previous fragment.

In case it is needed, styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fragments you have to make sure that the `setHasOptionsMenu()` is set in the `onCreate()` method and now the `onCreateView()` method.

Then be sure to set the toolbar(if added in the fragment layout) as the toolbar for the activity.

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        //moved to onCreate() method
        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //set toolbar as the default for the activity class if AppCompat
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(/*your toolbar goes here*/);

        //set toolbar is activity class is not AppCompat
        getActivity().setActionBar(/*your toolbar goes here*/);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_a, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_a) {
            //getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: What style is used on the activity this fragment is attached to? and does the activity used have an action bar with the menu methods overriden?

Comment: @DavisA. check the updated response, please let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much it did it this way and worked ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show()

Comment: please mark as correct answer if it helped you solve your problem @DavisA.